# Ruby on rails regex .match with options

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making a quiz system that matches user answers to the correct answer (a regexp statement). I've got it working great except I need to add a options ot the regex.

EDIT:

A basic version of what I have:

```
  if /#{@correct_answer_regex}/.match(@user_answer) != nil
      do stuff
```

I need something like this

```
 if (/#{@correct_answer_regex}/@regex_options).match(@user_answer) != nil
     do stuff
```

Can't get it to work.

Comment: the code you put here, seems with no sense, I think the application is not properly designed. So why `@quiz_question_response` is an object and have an attribute `answer`, what that whole object is supposed to contain.

Comment: You should post the classes definitions and examples of what you want to achieve to get good answers.

Comment: Take a look at ruby docs on regex options http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options